# Azure Disk Encryption is not enabled

Tags: azure, encryption, virtual-machine, disk

I have an Azure VM. It has one OS disk and one data disk. If I go to its disks in Azure portal, I see encryption enabled with a platform-managed key

[image]

But when I run the below az command

```
az vm encryption show --name vm1 --resource-group rg1
```

Azure Disk Encryption is not enabled

so my question is are these two different encryptions? How do I enable Azure disk encryption using the platform managed key on the Azure portal? My goal is to enable encryption at the host.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure Disk Encryption is not enabled,My goal is to enable encryption at the host.

1. **Platform-managed disk encryption:** This encryption is enabled at the platform level and is applied to the OS disk of the **Virtual Machine**. When you see **"Encryption Enabled"** on the disks in the `Azure portal`, it means that `platform-managed disk encryption` is turned on for those disks. This encryption is managed by `Azure` and uses a `platform-managed key`.
2. **Azure Disk Encryption:** This is a specific feature in Azure that allows you to enable encryption at the **OS** level for virtual machines. It uses **Azure Key Vault** to store the encryption keys. When you run the `az vm encryption show` command, it checks whether **Azure Disk Encryption** is enabled for the virtual machine's **OS** disk.

Enabling platform-managed disk encryption at the platform level `(as shown in the Azure portal)` does not automatically enable **Azure Disk Encryption** for the **VM's OS disk**. These are separate features.

When I check the `Disk encryption` status before enabling `ADE` for the `VM OS Disk`, I also got the same result as you.

**Result**

[image]

To enable **Azure Disk Encryption** for the `VM's OS` disk. follow the below steps.

1. Create an `Azure Key Vault` with the required permissions, and make sure to include the [--key-permissions wrapKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disk-encryption-key-vault-aad#set-the-key-vault-access-policy-for-the-azure-ad-app-with-azure-cli) permission to enable `disk encryption`.
2. Once the `Key Vault` is created, [enable Key Vault for disk encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disk-encryption-key-vault-aad#set-key-vault-advanced-access-policies-using-the-azure-cli) using the below command.

```
 az keyvault update --name "demovaulttest-test" --resource-group 'Imran' --enabled-for-disk-encryption "true"
```

2. [Encrypt a VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/encryption?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-encryption-enable-examples) using a `key vault` using the below command.

```
az vm encryption enable --resource-group <rg-Name> --name <VM-Name> --disk-encryption-keyvault demovaulttest-test --volume-type ALL
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Venkat V. Couple of follow-up questions.

1- "encryption at the host" is "platform managed disk encryption" or " Azure disk encryption"?
2- I have to turn the "Azure disk encryption" on couple of VMs using terraform. Do you have any links which can help in this regard?

Comment: 1."Encryption at the host" typically refers to "Azure Disk Encryption" (ADE) with "Platform Managed Disk Encryption." This means that the encryption is done at the virtual machine (host) level using Azure's platform-managed keys.
2. I have to turn the "Azure disk encryption" on couple of VMs using terraform-Kindly raise the another thread for same.

Comment: Below link suggests that "Encryption at the host" and "Azure Disk Encryption" (ADE) are two different things.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66652446/azure-disk-encryption-vs-encryption-at-host

Comment: "Encryption at the host" refers to Azure Disk Encryption, which encrypts your OS and data disks at the host level. Azure Disk Encryption can be enabled using either a platform-managed key or a customer-managed key1.

Platform-managed disk encryption is a type of Azure Disk Encryption where the encryption keys are managed by Azure. With platform-managed disk encryption, you don't need to worry about managing the keys yourself, as Azure takes care of this for you.